# Authorization requires a cascading parameter of type Task<AuthenticationState>. Consider using CascadingAuthenticationState to supply this

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server-side project that was set up with Individual Accounts. I scaffolded the AspNet.Core.Identity pages and wish to use a Blazor component inside one of the razor pages
by using the `<component>`tag helper.

My Razor page:

```xml
@page
@using SenseNet.Pages
@model WalletModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Wallet Data";
    ViewData["ActivePage"] = "WalletData";
}
@{
    Layout = "_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h3>@ViewData["Title"]</h3>
<component type="typeof(Counter)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

My Counter Blazor component:

```xml
@page "/counter"

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>
<h1>Counter</h1>

<AuthorizeView Policy="TwoFactorEnabled">
    <h1>Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!</h1>
    <p>You can only see this content if you're authenticated.</p>
</AuthorizeView>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

My CascadingAuthenticationState setup in App.razor:

```xml
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

When I load the page, I get `InvalidOperationException: Authorization requires a cascading parameter of type Task<AuthenticationState>. Consider using CascadingAuthenticationState to supply this.`

I have tried implementing the troubleshooting solutions as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#expose-the-authentication-state-as-a-cascading-parameter but I'm at a loss since even though I followed the cascading parameters suggestion as seen from the code above, it does not change the error message. When I remove the  tags from the Blazor component, it works.

Am I doing things in the wrong order here? Is it even possible to use `<AuthorizeView>` tags if the component is going to be rendered on a Razor page?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It worked by simply wrapping the `<AuthorizeView>` tag from my `Counter.razor` with `<CascadingAuthenticationState>`

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <AuthorizeView Policy="TwoFactorEnabled">
        <h1>Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!</h1>
        <p>You can only see this content if you're authenticated.</p>
    </AuthorizeView>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

I still don't understand why I had to do it there, since it was already done in the `App.razor` file and the troubleshooting steps specifically note:

> It's likely that the project wasn't created using a Blazor Server template with authentication enabled. Wrap a `<CascadingAuthenticationState>` around some part of the UI tree, for example in the App component (`App.razor`)

Therefore I think this is because I'm rendering it as a component in the Identity Razor Pages and that `App.razor` isn't used/triggered there, and so it can never pass it on.

I have also removed the `[CascadingParameter] private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }` as it simply wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same and debugged a while before I had the following realization:

*that error is thrown also when your program is cascading the `Task<AuthenticationState>` just fine, but it's `null`*.

It should never be `null` (as per the nullability attributes on `AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()`)

---

A fix can for instance be returning a dummy (unauthenticated) `AuthenticationState` until any authentication logic has run, like so:

```cs
public class MyAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider, IHostEnvironmentAuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private Task<AuthenticationState>? authenticationState;
    public override Task<AuthenticationState>? GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        return this.authenticationState ?? Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal()));
    }

    public void SetAuthenticationState(Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationState)
    {
        this.authenticationState = authenticationState;
    }
}
```

---

#### To help debugging

- Note that `AuthenticationState` being null leads to a different scenari, i.e. not `Authorzation requires a cascading parameter ...` but
  `NullReferenceException`).
- Inspect the value of your authentication state at the parameter injection site with a breakpoint in here:

```
@code {
    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        var debug = parameters.ToDictionary();
        return base.SetParametersAsync(parameters);
    }
    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }
}
```

- Set a breakpoint in your `GetAuthenticationStateAsync` to inspect if its returning `null`